# Can't fix "Error: Input length must be a multiple of 16 when decrypting with a pad cipher"

Tags: java, encryption, aes, jce

Ello! I am working a chat application that encrypts it's data through AES/CBC/PKCS5 Padding. It works through the client sending the encrypted message to the server where it is sent back and decrypted. Unfortunately, whenever I decrypt the message, I get the error as follows: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher. The encryption is based of this program :(http://www.scottjjohnson.com/blog/AesWithCbcExample.java) which works perfectly fine and I cannot see the difference between my code and that one except for that I must convert from string to byte array. Here is my code code:

Client (Encryption):

```
String message = textField.getText();
// generate a key
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init(128);  // To use 256 bit keys, you need the "unlimited strength" encryption policy files from Sun.
byte[] key = keygen.generateKey().getEncoded();
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

// build the initialization vector.  This example is all zeros, but it 
// could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

// initialize the cipher for encrypt mode
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);

// encrypt the message
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + encrypted + "\n");
System.out.println(encrypted);
out.println(encrypted);
textField.setText("");
```

Server Side:

```
String input = in.readLine();
writer.println("MESSAGE " + input);
```

Client (Decryption):

```
//DECRYPTION
System.out.println(line);
line = line.substring(8);
System.out.println(line);

// generate a key
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init(128);  // To use 256 bit keys, you need the "unlimited strength" encryption policy files from Sun.
byte[] key = keygen.generateKey().getEncoded();
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

// build the initialization vector.  This example is all zeros, but it 
// could be any value or generated using a random number generator.
byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

// reinitialize the cipher for decryption
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);

// decrypt the message
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(line.getBytes());
System.out.println("Plaintext: " + new String(decrypted) + "\n");
messageArea.append(name + ": " + decrypted + "\n");
messageArea.setCaretPosition(messageArea.getDocument().getLength());
```

Comment: there are a lot of similar questions, please do a little search.

Comment: Haha I have been researching all of those questions for the past week. My problem isn't the error itself, but how I keep receiving it even though I my input is a multiple of 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with cryptography. You are failing to transfer your data correctly between your clients and the server.

I'm fairly sure `out.println(encrypted)` is *not* what you want to be doing, although I'm not entirely clear since I don't know the type of `out`. Nor should you be calling `line.getBytes()` in your decryption code.

You should convert your ciphertext to a non-lossy string form, such as hexadecimal or base64. So, try:

```
out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(encrypted));
```

and

```
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(line));
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't give the old error anymore but now I receive this new one: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix it?